# Android: Memory error and size/quality of bitmap

Tags: android, animation, memory-leaks

I start 2 AnimationDrawables in the same activity and I have a memory error.
That is quite surprising because I reduced the size of the images (width = width of the screen) and I can't reduce it more as the quality would be lowere. For instance if I do width = width of the screen/2, it wortks but the quality is horrible

In the logcat it is written

```
02-19 10:56:44.769: E/dalvikvm-heap(3118): 383916-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-19 10:56:44.809: E/GraphicsJNI(3118): VM won't let us allocate 383916 bytes
02-19 10:56:44.809: W/dalvikvm(3118): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
02-19 10:56:44.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 10:56:44.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

I don't think I have a memory leak, yet checking this article http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html I tried to detect a potential memory leak but it seems to me there is not.

I would really need some help as it is not my first memory error in this project and I always struggle to handle that.

Here is my code:

```
private void startAnimation(AnimationDrawable animation1,AnimationDrawable animation2){
    int drawables[] = new int[] {R.drawable.fire1,R.drawable.fire2,R.drawable.fire3,R.drawable.fire4,R.drawable.fire5,R.drawable.fire6,R.drawable.fire7,R.drawable.fire8,R.drawable.fire9,R.drawable.fire10down2,R.drawable.fire11down2,R.drawable.fire12down2,R.drawable.fire13down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire15down2,R.drawable.fire16down2};
    int drawables2[] = new int[] {R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire14down2,R.drawable.fire10up,R.drawable.fire11up,R.drawable.fire12up,R.drawable.fire13up,R.drawable.fire14up,R.drawable.fire15up,R.drawable.fire16up};
    bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable[drawables.length];
    bitmapDrawable2 = new BitmapDrawable[drawables2.length];
    for (int i=0;i<drawables.length;i++) {
        bitmapDrawable[i]=new BitmapDrawable(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), drawables[i],width));
        Log.w("BITMAP","i="+i);
        bitmapDrawable2[i]=new BitmapDrawable(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), drawables2[i],width));
        animation1.addFrame(bitmapDrawable[i],50);
        animation2.addFrame(bitmapDrawable2[i],50);
    }
    animation1.setOneShot(true);
    animation2.setOneShot(true);
  image2.setLayoutParams(params);
        image2.setImageDrawable(animation1);
        image2.post(new Starter(animation1));
        image3.setLayoutParams(params);
        image3.setImageDrawable(animation2);
        image3.post(new Starter(animation2));

}
      class Starter implements Runnable {
          AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
          public Starter(AnimationDrawable animation) {
              this.animation = animation;
          }

          public void run() {
              animation.start();
          }
       }
```

How could I reduce the weight of the Bitmap (if it is necessary? the problem may somewhere else_ and keep the quality of theimages. I don't see where is the problem, I only use 30 images, other apps use much much more!

Answer (score 0):

you can create `ScaledBitmap` from yours to decrease its size for an EX:-

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, 600, 600,
                        false);
```

this will decrease its size to 600x600 and reduce its size. you can change the pixels for which u like

Comment: as I said when I decrease the size the quality does not satisfy me so I'd like other solutions

Answer (score 0):

here you'll re-size the quality.

```
   try {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;


             bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);


            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
```

here i'm using this method to get the image from the sdcard. and then display it.